# Running Windows Installer 4.5 in 64-bit Windows XP

Tags: sql-server, installation, windows-xp, 64-bit

I am trying to install Microsoft [SQL Server 2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server#SQL_Server_2008) on my 64-bit Windows XP operating system. Unfortunately, I need [Windows Installer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer) 4.5 to do this, and Windows Installer doesn't seem to run on 64-bit Windows XP. Is there a way around this?

Comment: OT, but according to the SQL Server info you should be able to install.  Installer 4.5 for XP 64 bit is here (use the 2003 64-bit install): http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=8483

Comment: @mkClark Did this get resolved?

Comment: I solved this using Plan B. I installed it on a virtual machine running 32-bit Windows XP.

Answer (score 2):

It is actually supported on Windows XP 64-bit.

Windows XP 64-bit is [Windows Server 2003](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2003) in disguise (but they often forget to mention Windows XP 64-bit - for instance, [PowerShell 2.0 can actually be installed on Windows XP 64-bit](http://vmjunkie.wordpress.com/2009/10/27/no-powershell-2-0-for-windows-xp-x64-not-so-fast/)). Thus locate "WindowsServer2003-KB942288-v4-x64.exe" ([direct download URL](http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/6/1/261fca42-22c0-4f91-9451-0e0f2e08356d/WindowsServer2003-KB942288-v4-x64.exe)), download and install.